# Problemas na execução de uma função

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Estava tentando criar uma função em Python que exibiria apenas os números pares dentro de um range de números, ela até que funciona e exibe os números, porém exibe também 'none' onde, imagino eu, serem os números ímpares.
    Se alguém souber como resolver isso e me ajudar serei grato.

[image: Essa é a função e o resultado]

Comment: Cara na próxima fez coloca o código. Fica muito ruim por imagem

Comment: Beleza, é a primeira vez usando o site kkk

Comment: Sem bronca cara. Se der coloca teu código. So pra ficar correto.

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que a sua função numpar não tem retorno quando o número não é par, como não possui um retorno explícito, ela vai acabar retornando None.

Um possível solução é fazer a sua função numpar não retornar um número e sim um valor lógico, indicando se o número recebido é par ou não:

```
def numpar(numero):
  return numero % 2 == 0

for numero in range(0,20):
  if numpar(numero):
    print(numero)
```

Comment: Obrigado, Daniel! Funcionou certinho, agora compreendo qual era o problema.